# json.NET parsing issue with twitter API data

Tags: c#, twitter, json.net

I have been using json.NET successfully in projects for some time now without any problems.  Last night I ran into my first case where json.NET crashed trying to parse json data returned from what should be a reliable source: the twitter API.

Specifically, this code causes the error:

```
string sCmdStr = String.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name={0}", sParam);
string strJson = _oauth.APIWebRequest("GET", sCmdStr, null);
JObject jsonDat = JObject.Parse(strJson);
```

In my case the sParam string contained about 25 twitter numeric Ids.  The twitter API call succeeded, but the json.NET Parse call failed with the following error:

> "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray"

Has anyone else run into this?  Does anyone know any way around it?  I am at a dead stop until I solve it.

Comment: I don't know much about the twitter api, but the source shouldn't really matter. Could you give us an example of what strJson will be containing?

Comment: Yes, you can see an example of the json data returned by twitter here: http://bit.ly/t8KBba.

Comment: @DrewStoddard If you had tried my answer, you would have seen what is wrong with `JObject.Parse` and why my Json.Net extension class works well. But as it seems you are not interested I removed the answer.

Comment: @L.B A shame you removed it, people other than the OP might have found it useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting the exact same error and eventually figured it out. Instead of using JObject.Parse use JArray.Parse. So here is your code:

```
string sCmdStr = String.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name={0}", sParam);
string strJson = _oauth.APIWebRequest("GET", sCmdStr, null);
JArray jsonDat = JArray.Parse(strJson);
```

You can then loop through the array and create a jobject for each individual tweet.

```
for(int x = 0; x < jsonDat.Count(); x++)
{
     JObject tweet = JObject.Parse(jsonDat[x].toString());
     string tweettext = tweet["text"].toString();
     //whatever else you want to look up
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It does look like it might solve the specific issue we were having.  We decided after having several similar problems with json reader classes to abandon json altogether in the case of the twitter API and use their XML protocol.  It was a good decision as we have been able to move at much higher development speed ever since.  XML may be more verbose, but the maturity and support surrounding it make it hard to beat.